# Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Tags: java

Quite new to Ubuntu 16, ran the following code in the terminal and got this exception. What am I supposed to do in order to fix it?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:126)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:198)
    at oop.ex2.GameGUI.createImageIcon(GameGUI.java:188)
    at oop.ex2.GameGUI.<clinit>(GameGUI.java:19)
    at SpaceShipFactory.createSpaceShips(SpaceShipFactory.java:8)
    at SpaceWars.createSpaceShips(SpaceWars.java:77)
    at SpaceWars.<init>(SpaceWars.java:55)
    at SpaceWars.main(SpaceWars.java:264)
```

edit: I tried to insert the following code and got a new error:

```
/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true ~oop/bin/ex2/SpaceWars h d
Error: Could not find or load main class 
.cs.course.current.oop.bin.ex2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error means you aren't running X. This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165761/java-cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value-of-t

Comment: I tried all of the things they said there none of them worked

Comment: If so please edit and update your question. Relevant information should never be in comments only. And while you're at that also post the actual code you used (*ran the following code in the terminal* but you only show the error message).

Comment: just edited again

Comment: You seriously need to start googling your error messages. Like before, this was found in less than a second: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean . Also this is a  new and unrelated error that  should be in a different question (and in a different site altogether: http://stackoverflow.com/ where generic programming questions belong).

Answer (score 5):

Run this in the terminal thus allowing connection to X11

```
xhost +
```

After your done installing or running your game then

```
xhost -
```

...for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Command given by @GregH747 and the following was what worked for me, at least in Fedora. Don't know about Ubuntu as I never came across in Ubuntu.

```
:~$ xhost +
```

Open $HOME/.bash_profile

```
JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.awt.headless=true
export JAVA_OPTIONS
```

Then

```
:~$ source ~/.profile
```

Then run your command or application again