X11 does not work no matter what I do
I am brand new to Linux but have decided I want a dedicated Minecraft server. I have gotten up to the point of running the .jar file but am met with this error java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
I have set up Xming on my local machine. I have also ensured X11 display is set up correctly in ssh_config. I have used the terminal program and putty with X11 enabled.
Ive been banging my head against a wall for 3 hours and cant figure out what to do.

What version of Ubuntu are you using. The title says no matter what you do but there is noting in the question about what you have done and what errors or messages you get when you do this. Please edit the question not in comments and add some details.

sorry I am using 24.04

24.04 is a release, but you've not said which Ubuntu product you're using. Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS doesn't include a GUI/window or Xorg server; as its intended to be used headless and via text only mode. Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS however does include a server but will default to Wayland (not Xorg), but your question does not give any details.  Please amend question with specific details.

This may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/904674/cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-0-0-as-the-value-of-the-display-vari
